# Большая буква в заголовке

Tags: прописная-строчная, заголовок

Можете сказать, каким образом правильно этот заголовок оформить? (Я думаю, вариант 1 — это правильный вариант).

```
1. Кот Барсик, или, другими словами, Кот, однажды-таки потерявшийся в леску.
```

```
2. Кот Барсик, или, Другими словами, кот, однажды-таки потерявшийся в леску.
```

```
3. Кот Барсик, или, Другими словами, Кот, однажды-таки потерявшийся в леску.
```

Comment: Если уберёте из заголовка «другими словами» (эти слова не нужны), смысл названия останется тем же самым: _Кот Барсик, или [другими словами] Кот, однажды-таки потерявшийся в **лесу**_ («в лесКу» у Вас, видимо, описка?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно: ***Кот Барсик**, **или Кот, однажды-таки потерявшийся в леску***

Это условное название двойных заголовков по правилу.

Союз ИЛИ заменяет "другими словами".

**[Розенталь](http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=22#pp22)**,  **пункт 5**

Если наименование состоит из двух названий, соединяемых союзом, то с прописной буквы пишется также первое слово второго названия: «Воевода, или Сон на Волге», «Похождения Чичикова, или Мёртвые души», «Дон Жуан, или Каменный гость», газета «Юнайтед Стейтс ньюс энд Уорлд рипорт».

**Примечание**. Союз ИЛИ может иметь **пояснительное** значение и для нарицательных существительных, что указано в **правиле [Розенталя](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=119#pp119)**:

2. Пояснительные члены предложения могут присоединяться союзом или (‘то есть’): Из лесного оврага неслось воркованье **диких голубей, или горлинок** (Акс.);

Answer (score 0):

• Точка в конце заголовка не нужна.

> **7.** В конце заголовков точка не ставится, независимо от их структуры (односоставное номинативное предложение, двусоставное и т. д.)... [Розенталь]

•• Первая часть заголовка: *Кот Барсик*;
вторая часть заголовка: ***Д**ругими словами, **к**от, однажды-таки потерявшийся в леску* (если "другими словами" собственно входит в эту часть; "кот" — со строчной буквы).

> [**Вопрос № 286933**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%2C%20%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE#:%7E:text=%D0%95%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D1%85%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82,%2C%20%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%A1%20%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC%20%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%C2%BB.&text=%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%3A%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%D1%8B%20%D0%B8%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5.)
> Скажите, пожалуйста, почему в названии фильма "Ирония судьбы, или С легким паром!" стоит запятая и после "или" еще и с прописной буквы?!
> **Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
> Таковы правила. Конструкция *С легким паром* — это пояснительный член предложения, т. е. представляющий собой второе наименование по отношению к первому. Если пояснительный член предложения присоединяется союзом *или* (в значении «то есть»), перед *или* ставится запятая.
> Если наименование художественного произведения состоит из двух названий, соединенных союзом *или*, то с прописной буквы пишется также первое слово второго названия, напр.: *«Двенадцатая ночь, **или Что** угодно», «Ирония судьбы, **или С** легким паром».*

••• Правильное оформление заголовка такое (ваши варианты не подходят — запятая после "или" не нужна):
***Кот Барсик, или Другими словами, кот, однажды-таки потерявшийся в леску***

Разъяснение после комментария (*лес — в лесу, лесо́к — в леску́*)

Это местный (второй предложный) падеж.
*— Завтра, дядюшко, как отзвонят к вечерне, будь **в леску** за Облепихиным двором, там объявлюсь я...* (А. П. Чапыгин. Гулящие люди).